# System freezes for a few seconds after waken up

Tags: performance, sleep-wake

I have a 2017 Macbook Air (Monterrey). My old system was very cluttered so I reset it. After the first few days I never realized anything odd but when my holidays were over I realized that every time I wake my laptop from sleep two freezes lasting from 3-5 seconds up to 10 seconds. One freeze happens on the lock screen and the other freeze happens when I am logged in (around 30 seconds after). The second freeze used to happen a lot but now it hasn't

After Login lag spike

[image]

I am not sure about the previous spikes but I am concerned about the 2 spikes even thouhg one freeze occoured.

IF there is any way i can see which process is causing this would be helpful

EDIT:
I was watchign some media and when the freeze happened the audio was stuttering?

Comment: Is it a freeze or is the system unresponsive while the loaded apps re-establish their previous states.  If you’re seeing CPU spikes, the CPU is working and not frozen.

Comment: I might have not explained this well but what I am expiercing is that i cant move my mouse press any keys and any audio that was playing stutters.

Comment: Open Activity Monitor and see which processes are spiking.

Comment: How do I see each indivual process cpu usage history?

Comment: The list of processes.

Comment: The activity monitor shows all **current** process information. What i can't access is the **history**

Comment: It doesn’t log that kind of history.  Keep it open so you can access it quickly when this occurs.

Comment: In the event of a freeze how should one open the activity monitor?